# Cox Hazard in function R

Tags: r, function, cox

I have problem with reference to the variable in R.

Look for my easy function:

```
 CoxStep <- function(dataset,a,b){  
 m1 = coxph(Surv(b,a)~.-dataset[,b]-dataset[,a] ,data=dataset)
  summary(m1)
  }
```

I call the function as follow:

CoxStep(data, Alive1, FU_3M)

where FU_3M is a column of time
Alive1 is a column of event
and data is my dataset which contain variables below and other variables.

Function does not see this Alive1 and FU_3M.

Could you help me? Any proposition?

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix is to have your function take a formula as argument:

```
CoxStep <- function(dataset, form){  
 m1 = coxph(form, data=dataset)
  summary(m1)
  }
```

and then call it with `CoxStep(dataset, Surv(a, b) ~ . - a - b)`.

You could build a helper function if you want for that formula:

```
my_form = function(a, b) {
    as.formula(sprintf('Surv(%1$s, %2$s) ~ . - %1$s - %2$s', a, b)
}
```

`my_form` can be called *with strings*, e.g., `my_form('a', 'b')`, so you could put it all together with `CoxStep(dataset, my_form('a', 'b'))`.